# Azure publish using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-powershell

Is there a way to publish a cloud service to Azure without a "deploy project"? My actual challenge is to publish the same cloud service to a lot of cloud services, using different configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adilson - you can deploy to Azure without a deployment project but you'd struggle as you would need to hand craft the necessary package (files to deploy) and configuration elements.  As kwill said there are PowerShell Cmdlets for creating cloud services ([New-AzureService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495119.aspx)) that are at that point an empty container into which you can deploy items using other Cmdlets.

I have a Gist that shows how to create a new empty Cloud Service here: https://gist.github.com/sjwaight/4186f90f6ae111cd7c52#file-02-setup-cloudservices-ps1 which was a part of a bigger set of blog posts I did on deploying to Azure (http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/11/04/deploy-an-ultra-high-availability-mvc-web-app-on-microsoft-azure-part-2/).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague so it is hard to know exactly what you are trying to do, but there are several ways to deploy a package to Azure.  I am guessing that the Azure Powershell cmdlets will be your best option.  Essentially you would call Upload-Package, then Create-Deployment.  More details at http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2014/02/06/deploying-cloud-services-to-azure-with-powershell/.